# Full PJAX website vs partial PJAX website

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, github, pjax

I'm using PJAX for all the links in my website, while Github is using it just for repository files and sections.

Why Github is disabling PJAX for main links, is it a performance issue?!

I think PJAX is there for speeding up the website!!!

Answer (score 0):

To implement PJAX you have to put all your javascript to the single file(View file), and you have to duplicate the scripts in both pjax success or end function and document.ready function so the file gets bulk the result takes more time to load the page at first time. so it is recommend to use pjax for a simple site or the pages that are not required more js. :)